# Redux Action only dispatched on refresh and not after redirect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I used a history.push("/") to redirect to my homepage from another page and the homepage has a ProjectList component that dispatches an action:

App.js

```
function App(){
    return(
        <Router>
            <NavBar></NavBar>
            <Switch>
                <Route
                    path="/createProject"
                    component={withAuthentication(CreateProjectPage)}
                ></Route>
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/"
                    component={withAuthentication(HomePage)}
                ></Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
export default App
```

CreateProjectPage

```
function CreateProject(){
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        ...
        dispatch(createNewProject({...}));
        history.push("/");
    }
    return (
        <div>
            ...
            <Button
                onClick={submitHandler}
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
              >
                Submit
            </Button>
          
        </div>
    )
    
}
```

HomePage

```
export default function HomePage(props){
    return (
        <div>
            <ProjectList level="one"/>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

ProjectList Component:

```
export default function ProjectList({level}){
    console.log(level); //onRedirect, this gets called

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("dispatch returnAllProjects called") //onRedirect, this does not get called
        dispatch(returnAllProjects());
    }, [dispatch]);
    ...
    return ...
}
```

only on refresh this returnAllProjects is called.
This results in getting undefined objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post more of your code, how does the Homepage component looks like?

Comment: `dispatch` is a stable reference so it won't trigger an effect to run again after the initial mounting execution, hence why you need to hard reload the page to get it to run again. https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for the link! But I'm redirecting to this homepage with history.push("/")...how come it only works once I hit the refresh button?

Comment: Can you provide more context as to how these components are being rendered? From `ProjectList` all the way up the tree to the `Router`?

Comment: @DrewReese Wondering if this is sufficient? withAuthentication is a HOC used for userAuthentication

Comment: I think the inline HOC *could* be adversely affecting your app, it looks to be generating new components each render (though I think would be complete opposite issue you have). Have you tried decorating the components outside the component and attaching the decorated component to the `Route`'s `component` prop? Outside of this is it possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @DrewReese I don't think I know how to be honest...but let me try it out!

Comment: If you have your project hosted in a github repo you can directly import it into codesandbox.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm really sorry about this but I don't think I know what "inline HOC" and "decorating the components outside the component and attaching the decorated component" means or how to fix it? Sorry I'll go try to read up about it >.<

Comment: When you `component={withAuthentication(HomePage)}` then every time the `Router` rerenders you'll actually re-run the HOC to return a decorated component. I was asking if you did this decorating only once, outside the router component, if your issue still persisted. Outside router component, something like `const HomePageWithAuth = withAuthentication(HomePage);`, and then the route component is `component={HomePageWithAuth}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `location` as dependency if you want the effect to get called after redirect:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
export default function ProjectList({level}){
    const location = useLocation(); // <--- listen to location
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(returnAllProjects());
    }, [dispatch, location]); //<--- location is added as dependency
    ...
    return ...
}
```

Comment: Hey @yaya! Thanks a lot for this! However, I tried it out and it didn't work :(